# Typescript error: Property 'code' does not exist on type 'KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling

I have the following, which is currently producing a type error. Typescript error: Property 'code' does not exist on type 'KeyboardEvent'

```
  const onKeyDownSim = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const element = event.target as HTMLElement;
    if (event.code === 'Space') element.click();
  };
```

looking at the definition for the KeyboardEvent in React, I understand why it's complaining as the 'code' property doesn't exist here. It does however have all the old methods for doing the same thing. deprecated charCode etc. Any ideas how to work around this?

```
interface KeyboardEvent<T = Element> extends SyntheticEvent<T, NativeKeyboardEvent> {
    altKey: boolean;
    /** @deprecated */
    charCode: number;
    ctrlKey: boolean;
    /**
     * See [DOM Level 3 Events spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#keys-modifier). for a list of valid (case-sensitive) arguments to this method.
     */
    getModifierState(key: string): boolean;
    /**
     * See the [DOM Level 3 Events spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#named-key-attribute-values). for possible values
     */
    key: string;
    /** @deprecated */
    keyCode: number;
    locale: string;
    location: number;
    metaKey: boolean;
    repeat: boolean;
    shiftKey: boolean;
    /** @deprecated */
    which: number;
}
```

Comment: You should use [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values - Key for Space is " " - which isn't the most readable.. assume that its reliable? It works btw, it's just a bit gross. const SPACE_KEY = ' '; and comparing that I guess is the workaround

Comment: Well, it should be reliable for modern browser. Older ones might use "Spacebar", maybe you should handle that too. Agree about readability though.

Comment: @lbsn - add your comment as the answer and I'll accept. I'll work with this, thanks.

Comment: Apparently `code` property has been added in React 17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `key` property to determine [what character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) corresponds with the key event: the value for space will be `" "` for modern browser (`"Spacebar"` for older ones).

Note that according to the [Changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#react-dom-2) the `code` property has been added to `React.KeyboardEvent` in React v17, so upgrading your React version should allow you to use `code`.

Also note that, as you might know, `code` and `key` are not exactly the same: `code` represents the physical key on the keyboard, while `key` represents the generated character.